# How to call this file in my main file?

Tags: java, constructor

```
package harjutamine;

public class algandmed{

    Button[] whitebutton= new Button[2];
    Button[] blackbutton= new Button[2];

    public algandmed(){

        whitebutton[0] = new Button(5, 1);
        whitebutton[1] = new Button(5, 3);

        blackbutton[0] = new Button(0, 0);
        blackbutton[1] = new Button(0, 2);
    }
}
```

This is basic information for my main file.
I have tried `algandmed();` and `algandmed a = new algandmed();` to call the code in my main file which don't work and I don't know why, I'd be thankful if someone explained why those wouldn't work and what would work.

Main

```
package harjutamine;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Checkerboard extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public void drawFrame(Graphics g, int frameNumber, int width, int height) {

        int row;   // Row number, from 0 to 7
        int col;   // Column number, from 0 to 7
        int x, y;   // Top-left corner of square
        for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            //Kabelaud
            for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                x = col * 50;
                y = row * 50;
                if ((row % 2) == (col % 2)) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
            }
        }
//This is where I try to call the function, but it doesn't work
        algandmed aa = new algandmed();


        for (Button n: (whitebutton)) {
            x = n.col * 50 + 4;
            y = n.row * 50 + 4;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawOval(x, y, 40, 40);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }

        for (Button n: (blackbutton)) {
            x = n.col * 50 + 4;
            y = n.row * 50 + 4;
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawOval(x, y, 40, 40);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }




    }

    //------ Implementation details: DO NOT EXPECT TO UNDERSTAND THIS ------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Checkerboard");
        Checkerboard drawingArea = new Checkerboard();
        drawingArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        window.setContentPane(drawingArea);
        drawingArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(390, 390));
        window.pack();
        window.setLocation(100, 50);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false); // The user can't change the size.
        Timer frameTimer = new Timer(20, drawingArea);
        window.setVisible(true);
        //frameTimer.start(); // commented out so we don't get an animation
    } // end main

    private int frameNum;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        frameNum++;
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawFrame(g, frameNum, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```

Button

```
package harjutamine;
public class Button{
    int row;
    int col;
    public Button(int r, int c){
        row = r;
        col = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: `which don't work` Probably you should explain what happens instead of work? Are there any errors/exceptions/messages? Did you receive an unexpected result?

Comment: Post the code that calls this class.

Comment: instead of saying "y r u no read my mind?", consider including the error message that you see that leads you to believe that it is not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? What does your main method look like? You need to provide lots more information.

Comment: Okay sorry, last thread people got angry because I gave too much information. Updated post with main file.

Comment: Can you also post the complete error message you're getting? What is the output? What does "it doesn't work" mean? (Others have already asked you these questions; there's a reason they did.)

Comment: If i replace algandmed aa = new algandmed(); with the code that's in class algandmed(); then it prints out a checkerboard with buttons, but right now the for loops below it say can't find symbol "blackbutton"/"whitebutton"

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to say is that your code does not compile. There is no declaration for a Variable whitebutton in your drawFrame method. Therefor the compiler won't compile your code. If you simply paste the code algandmed then you have a declaration of whitebutton. However this is probably not what you wanted. Think about which class should hold/own the Button Arrays. If you decide to put them in the alganmed class you need to provide a correct variable declaration.`aa.whitebutton` should work because you created an instance of alganmed named aa. Since you are in the same package and whitebutton is default visibility you can access it directly from your main method. Note however that this is not good practice. You should not access another classes internal data directly. Try to think of methods that encapsulate the data of alganmed instead.